# Hashtables Python put method showing IndexError

Tags: python

Below is my `SimpleHashTable` class.

The `put(self, key)` method should determines where the key is placed in the hashtable when a collision occurs (i.e., calculates the next available index position). Linear probing will be used for collision resolution. I am to do the the following steps:
Invoke the `get_hash_index(key)` to get the original index position.
Use a while loop to get the next available position.
Store the key into the hashtable according to the available index position.

```
class SimpleHashTable:
    def __init__(self, size=7):
        self.size = size
        self.slots = [None] * self.size
        
    def __str__(self):
        return "{}".format(self.slots)
    
    def get_hash_index(self, key):
        self.key = key
        self.hkey = key % self.size
        return self.hkey
        
    def new_hash_code(self, index):
        count = 0
        while count < self.size:
            if self.slots[index] == None:
                return index
            index += 1
            count += 1
        return None
                
    def put(self, key): #issue here
        code = self.get_hash_index(key)
        if self.slots[code] != None:
            code = self.new_hash_code(code)
        self.slots[code] = key
        
        
    def __len__(self):
        count = 0
        for item in self.slots:
            if item != None:
                count += 1
        return count
```

Test:

```
my_hash_table = SimpleHashTable(13)
my_hash_table.put(12)
my_hash_table.put(24)
my_hash_table.put(36)
my_hash_table.put(48)
my_hash_table.put(31)
my_hash_table.put(77)
my_hash_table.put(43)
```

Output getting:

```
***Error***
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "__tester__.python3", line 87, in <module>
    my_hash_table.put(77)
  File "__tester__.python3", line 26, in put
    code = self.new_hash_code(code)
  File "__tester__.python3", line 17, in new_hash_code
    if self.slots[index] == None:
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Comment: @khelwood: What you're thinking of is separate chaining, one method of resolving collisions. Picking a different bucket is also a viable option, known as [open addressing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open_addressing). (CPython's own dict implementation uses a form of open addressing.) The code in the question is broken not because picking a different bucket is fundamentally wrong, but because it's running off the end of `self.slots` instead of wrapping around.

Comment: @user2357112supportsMonica I stand corrected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is in the `new_hash_code` method. Your current code starts from the current value of index, but increments it without testing it against `self.size`. You should simply reset it to 0 when reaching the top:

```
def new_hash_code(self, index):
    count = 0
    while count < self.size:
        if index == self.size:   # prevent out of range error...
            index = 0
        if self.slots[index] == None:
            return index
        index += 1
        count += 1
    return None
```

Answer (score 1):

if index is 99 and size is 50

index becomes 49

then

1. count = 0
2. index = 49
3. if my_table[index] is not None

   1. index becomes 50, count becomes 1
   2. count is still less than 50, but index is now out of bounds

beyond that ... your hash table wont work right ... since the hash wont align with the buckets...

you will not be able to implement a better hashtable than builtin dictionary, but you can certainly make a working hashtable